# How can I upload my own pdf to display in Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-developer-api, androidpdfviewer

I am currently using [2.8.2 version](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) of AndroidPdfViewer were it only displays pdf from internet links (with .pdf extension url) , I want to display my own pdf how can I do so, currently using Android Studio, language Kotlin

I was following [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/load-pdf-from-url-in-android-with-kotlin/) geeksforgeeks article and was able to fetch and display pdfs from internet which are already available but i want my own pdf to display and I don't have my own website.

Comment: "were it only displays pdf from internet links" -- that library is not limited to downloading PDFs. It can view local PDFs as well. This is covered in [the documentation](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer#load-a-pdf-file). See methods like `fromFile()`, `fromAsset()`, and `fromStream()`.

Comment: Okay, but in our project we have to upload many PDFs(20mb/pdf) in our app which will increase the size of the app